# access span with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, sharepoint

i have this code :

```
<span id="ctl00_SiteMapPath1" >
   <span>ParentSite</span>
   <span>Site</span>
   <span>SubSite</span>
   <span>SubSubSite</span>
</span>
```

i want to get the inner html of the last span (SubSubsite) and the inner html of his parent (SubSite),
the spans are generated automatically according the number of subsites created.

is it possible to do this using jQuery?
thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should sort you out:

```
$('#ct100_SiteMapPath1').last().html();
```

for the last one and:

```
$('#ct100_SiteMapPath1').last().prev().html();
```

for the one before that (a sibling, by the way, not a parent)

Ref: http://api.jquery.com/last/

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers, in fact i have a top link bar like this :

MyParentSite>MySite>MySubSite>MyNSite,

i want to get always the last element (MyNSite) and the last-2 element (MySite in this case),

your solution works fine in the case of the last element but eq(2) displays '>'

did i miss something?

Answer (score 0):

First you can use `clientidmode='static'` and then in js:

```
$("#SiteMapPath1 span:last-child").html()//this one get html of subsubsite

$("#SiteMapPath1").children().eq(2).html()//this one get subsite
```

Answer (score 0):

That would be:

```
$('#ctl00_SiteMapPath1 > span').last().html();
```

```js
alert( $('#ctl00_SiteMapPath1 > span').last().html() );
$('span[id]:has(span)').on('click',function() {
  alert( $(this).children('span').last().html() );
});
```

```css
span[id] {
   display:block;
   border:1px solid #000;
   margin:10px;
   padding:10px;
}
span > span {
  background-color: #c0c0c0;
  display:inline-block;
  width:24%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="ctl00_SiteMapPath1" >
   <span>ParentSite</span>
   <span>Site</span>
   <span>SubSite</span>
   <span>SubSubSite1</span>
</span>
<span id="ctl00_SiteMapPath2" >
   <span>ParentSite</span>
   <span>Site</span>
   <span>SubSite</span>
   <span>SubSubSite2</span>
</span>
<span id="ctl00_SiteMapPath3" >
   <span>ParentSite</span>
   <span>Site</span>
   <span>SubSite</span>
   <span>SubSubSite3</span>
</span>
<span id="ctl00_SiteMapPath4" >
   <span>ParentSite</span>
   <span>Site</span>
   <span>SubSite</span>
   <span>SubSubSite4</span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var lastSpan = $("#ctl00_SiteMapPath1 span").last().html();
var beforeSpan = $("#ctl00_SiteMapPath1 span").eq(2).html();
alert("Before last span:"+beforeSpan);
alert("Last span:"+lastSpan);
```

#### Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/nnyq4eh5/